# GWT Library creation

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt library which I include to my other project via:

```
inherits name="org.mylib.Mylib" />
```

All the classes in the library project is under org.mylib.client*

This works fine.

However I added packages that contains classes that I want to be included in the library, i.e to be called within a GWT client side code.

Will it work if I don't put the classes under org.mylib.client?

Packages like: `x.io`, `x.nio` etc. to be usable within a GWT client side code.

Comment: They need to be Java source files, not just classes. You may have meant this, but that part of your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to be Java source files, not just classes. You may have meant this, but that part of your question is ambiguous.

Assuming they are sources, you do need to include them in a package that you've declared to GWT contains sources. Either by inheriting a module which has this, or by adding it yourself in your main module. In short, somewhere you need this:

`<source path="/mySourcePath" />`

where `/mySourcePath` is the location of the sources for this `x.io` pckage.